# 1920s Photography 35mm Printing

Tags: printing, 35mm, history

I am researching for a historical fiction novel.  Background is 1921, United States.  Using an American Tourist Multiple camera.[American Tourist](https://www.mikeeckman.com/2019/05/kepplers-vault-38-herbert-huesgen-tourist-multiple/)  I am trying to figure out making prints, what type of enlarger would be available.  Character has access to a city newspaper office or a portrait studio, but is just an amateur with some darkroom experience.  I think (please correct me if I'm wrong) that portrait studios would not be using 35mm.
Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would a professional photographer in 1920s Europe have access to an enlarger?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/113627/would-a-professional-photographer-in-1920s-europe-have-access-to-an-enlarger)

Comment: Conversation regarding answer in comments has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129180/discussion-on-question-by-shannont-1920s-photography-35mm-printing).

Answer (score 3):

By 1920 the photofinishing industry was well established. These firms were advertising film developing and printing services, including enlarging. Camera stores were common, and photofinishing was one of their offerings which also included printing and enlarging. Additionally, photographers worked out of a shop that typically did their own film developing, printing, and enlarging. Most such shops advertised photofinishing services.

Since photofinishing is deeply rooted in chemistry, it was a natural for the local drugstore (pharmacist – chemists),to offer photofinishing services. This evolved into drugstores selling cameras and films. Thus, the drugstore became a key player for film developing, printing with enlarging service.

By 1920, in a metropolitan area, amateur photographers would have no difficulty getting film developed, printed and enlarged.

I entered the photofinishing business in the 1950's. In the backroom was a plethora of retired equipment including enlargers that were used in the 1020's.